# How to autowire RedisTemplate<String,Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I want to use RedisTemplate in spring boot. I can use StringRedisTemplate successfully, but I cant use RedisTemplate. here is the code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RedisEntityTests {

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, RedisEntity> redisTemplate;

    // This test case can run successfully.
    @Test
    public void testString() {
        // save string
        stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set("aaa", "111");
        Assert.assertEquals("111", stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get("aaa"));
    }

    // This test case I got error.
    @Test
    public void testObject() throws Exception {
        // save object
        RedisEntity redisEntity = new RedisEntity("Tom", 20);
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(redisEntity.getName(), redisEntity);

        Assert.assertEquals(20, (redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("Tom")).getAge().longValue());
    }
}
```

Then, run the test method：testObject(), Here is the error report：

> 2017-12-17 16:12:12.079 ERROR 4708 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@49070868]
>   to prepare test instance [springworld.RedisEntityTests@2f3cd727]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'springworld.RedisEntityTests':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisTemplate'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
>   ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>   ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>   ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>   [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
>   [.cp/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     ... 29 common
>   frames omitted

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined the Bean which you will like to use for injecting in RedisTemplate.You can resolve it creating a configuration file.

```
@Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate< String, Object > redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate< String, Object > template =  new RedisTemplate< String, Object >();
        template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
        template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        return template;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is good，but I want this ：RedisTemplate<String, User>，RedisTemplate<String, Person> and so on，not only RedisTemplate< String, Long >.I want to reuse that code. any suggestions？ Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try using Object.

Comment: Still confused me. and it seems the spring boot 1.5.9 cant inject JedisConnectionFactory like that. I do like this it works, Just 
`
    @Bean
    RedisTemplate< String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        ...
        template.setConnectionFactory( factory);
        ...
    }
`
but I got another problem: ClassCastException，String cant be cast to Object

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no easy way of doing that. Your problem is similar to [DRYing up a generic RedisTemplate in Spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208010/drying-up-a-generic-redistemplate-in-spring-4)

There is some trick with serialization [Spring RedisTemplate : Serialise multiple Model classes into JSON.Need to use Multiple RedisTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672245/spring-redistemplate-serialise-multiple-model-classes-into-json-need-to-use-mu)

Comment: Thanks，it seems like the first answer.